# Error installing psycopg2: unrecognized option `-Wdeclaration-after-statement'

Tags: python, django, gcc, shared-hosting, psycopg2

I'm on a shared hosting provider, trying to install psycopg2 in order to get Django up and running with psql.

I ran `$ pip install psycopg2`

and got following error

```
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes 
-fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.5 (dt dec pq3 ext)" 
-DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x080205 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BOOLEAN=1 
-DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -I/home3/n/norcal/python/include/python2.7 -I. 
-I/usr/local/pgsql-8.2/include -I/usr/local/pgsql-8.2/include/server 
-c psycopg/psycopgmodule.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/psycopg/psycopgmodule.o 
-Wdeclaration-after-statement

cc1: error: unrecognized option `-Wdeclaration-after-statement'

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I did some googling and found that I might be missing python-dev and libpq-dev, but I'm unable to find instructions on how to install those without aptitude - which I don't have access to on my shared hosting provider.

Any ideas?

Thanks a million in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Problem is, that `-Wdeclaration-after-statement` isn't supported by your version of gcc.

A hacky solution is, to remove this unsupported option from the compile command. A better solution would be, to upgrade you gcc.

After you get this error, grep to find where `declaration-after-statement` is used:

```
$ grep -r "declaration-after-statement" ./virtual_env_dir
virtual_env_dir/build/psycopg2/setup.py: '-Wdeclaration-after-statement')
```

Edit the setup.py and comment the corresponding code-block:

```
''''
for extension in self.extensions: 
    extension.extra_compile_args.append(
        '-Wdeclaration-after-statement')
''''
```

Re-run the build via `$ pip install psycopg2`.